# Dictionaries in Python and different ways of accessing it

Tags: python, dictionary

Which is the best way to access the dictionary in Python as far as speed and writing Pythonic code is concerned? As, both return the same results, I like the 2nd approach better as it is more intuitive.

```
for name, number in phonebook.iteritems():
    print "Phone number of %s is %d" % (name, number)
```

OR

```
for key in phonebook:
    print "Phone number of %s is %d" % (key, phonebook[key])
```

Comment: I think this is really just personal preference. There's no real difference in performance, memory-usage, etc. between the two that I'm aware of.

Comment: whichever way your heart desires

Comment: I find this question interesting (because I've been wondering about which idiom to use myself). I agree, though, that a question asking about the "best" way is too unspecific - best in what way? Readability, speed, memory usage, Pythonicity...?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks Tim, by best way I meant speed and 'Pythonicity'

Comment: I am sick and tired of this download business at Stack-Exchange, Q & A forum is not at all constructive and is filled with snobs who think they know too much to even comment before down-voting a post. I don't know what happened to the feeling of helping each other out, as we are all here to learn. Would love to see a Q & A forum without the down-vote option!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably quite subjective (and timing the two examples showed no difference in execution speed), but I would prefer the first approach if you're going to access each value of the dictionary anyway.

If you're only going to access certain values, then I would suggest the second approach. For example:

```
for key in phonebook:
    if key.startswith("Sm"):
        print "Phone number of %s is %d" % (key, phonebook[key])
```